# Sticky Posts & Posts Per Page

Tags: wp-query, sticky-post

I notice that sticky posts will disregard the `posts_per_page` param? Like I have a query like

```
$q = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, ... ));
```

If there are 3 sticky posts, I will get 6 posts? (its abit strange tho why 6 not 7 (4+3)) I dont want to ignore sticky posts. How can I force the posts per page limit? eg, I have 10 sticky, I still get only 4 posts.

One way I can think of is a counter that counts to 4 and exit the loop. But there isnt a WP way? This appears to be more of a bug to me?

Comment: by using the `ignore_sticky_posts` argument you're not excluding them from the list, you're just treating them like normal posts. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: More than one year later: Any progress on this topic?

Comment: I cannot replicate this, seems to behave exactly as described wanted behavior.

Comment: This is reproducible bug and is a known bug; being tracked at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27282