# Sticky post appears twice

Tags: posts, query, sticky-post

I am trying to modify the number of posts_per_page in the loop. This way:

```
function posts_per_page($query) {
    $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 3;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_per_page', 11);
```

The problem I have is that when I do so, then sticky posts appear twice in the loop: first one at the begining of the loop and second one in their original position.
So in this case, the first page has 4 posts (3 of loop without sticky + the sticky post), and the sticky post will appear (again) later in its "page" with other 2 posts.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

After doing quite much research I realised sticky posts appear always in the first page. If the original sticky post was already in the first page then only the sticky appears (this post only will appear one).
I needed to know exacty how many posts will my query have, but $wp_query->found_posts was not counting the sticky posts. And if I did $wp_query->found_posts + get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) wouldnt be correct as it doesnt consider the 'sticky post from first page' I said before and also counts non-published sticky posts.

With $wp_query->posts I get the real number of posts in my first page, so:

```
$sticky = count($wp_query->posts) - get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

if ($sticky<0) {$sticky=0;}//In case there is only one page of results
```

Now $sticky will have the real number of sticky posts.

Comment: Just a note, pre_get_posts is a action and not a filter

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not an issue but normal WordPress behaviour. When you mark a post as a sticky it will be at the top of the list **and** it will appear in it's original postition as well, unless the original position is on the first page. A sticky will appear at the top of the posts and in it's original position but it will not appear twice on the same page.

You might want to do something like this:

```
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if ( !in_array( $post->ID, $do_not_duplicate ) ) { // check IDs         
// display posts ...
        the_title();

//store id in "do not duplicate
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
    }
endwhile;
?>
```

source with minor edit: http://wpengineer.com/1719/filter-duplicate-posts-in-the-loop/

Comment: It was throwing an error, I created $do_not_duplicate=[]; before the loop and $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; to $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;  Im loading articles of next pages via ajax so the problem persists. Thanks

Comment: "sticky it will be at the top of the list and it will appear in it's original postition as well".  This is not exactly correct, if the sticky post is in the first page, it wont appear twice, only one time as sticky.

Comment: Just did thorough testing and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

More correct would be to use the `set` method.

```
function posts_per_page($query) {
    $query->set('posts_per_page',3);
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_per_page', 11);
```

Try that.

Note: I can't duplicate this multiple sticky issue. If that doesn't solve things edit your question with more detail. That may be theme specific or due to a plugin.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is still there. There are no plugins so it must be a problem somewhere else in the theme. Until I find the solution ill turn off sticky posts $query->set('ignore_sticky_posts',1);

Answer (score 0):

Consider a case where one needs the following:

- Keep sticky posts at the top.
- Not duplicate sticky posts in later pages
- Have each page be limited to a specific number of posts (even the first page).

It is very complex to do by setting parameters in the `pre_get_posts` hook because there is no simple way to set the number of posts for the first page.  WordPress naturally sends back all sticky posts + the posts on the first page.  It is not a good idea to try to calculate a new value of `posts_per_page` based on the number of `sticky posts` of the following complications.

- There are many cases to consider.  Sometimes `sticky posts` are less that the `posts_per_page`, sometimes more, and sometimes equal.  Each case will need to be dealt with separably.
- There is no way to deal with the case where the number of `sticky posts` exceeds `posts_per_page` as described in [an answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76620/sticky-posts-exceed-posts-per-page-limit)

Therefore the solution is to modify the code executes `the loop`.

```
                global $wp_query, $post;
                // Setup manual paging scheme.
                $page_requested        = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] ? $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : 1;
                $number_per_page       = $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];
                $first_post_to_display = ( $page_requested - 1 ) * $number_per_page + 1;
                $last_post_to_display  = $first_post_to_display + $number_per_page - 1;
                $current_post          = 1;
                // Re query posts without paging so it won't duplicate the sticky posts.
                $query = new WP_Query( array( 'nopaging' => true ) );
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                    $query->the_post();
                    $should_display_this_post = $current_post >= $first_post_to_display && $current_post <= $last_post_to_display;
                    if ( $should_display_this_post ) {
                        ?>
                  <Template code to output post content here>
 
                <?php } 
                 ++$current_post;
                 endwhile;
?>
```

Explanation:

- Re query all posts without paging in order to remove duplicates (while preserving the high priority of `sticky posts`.
- Manually Calculate which posts should be displayed based on the requested page number and the desired `posts_per_page`.